# Render three charts to the same div to save them as one image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I have three pie charts that display three different values. At the moment they are sent to three different containers, appearing in a row as I am using Bootstrap to give each container div a 3 column layout.

I want to save an image of the charts, and I can do it by attaching the functionality to each container separately. But what this results in is three saved images that on their own mean little, without the context of the other charts.

I have managed to send all three charts to the one div container, but the problem is that they render on top of one another, so despite setting the options to as follows:

```
options: {
    chartArea: {left: 20},
    backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
    ...
    }
```

I am still only seeing the one chart appearing. Is there anyway around this?

[image: Example of Pie-Charts in one div]